# HTML5 video not playing now I've put it live

Tags: html, .htaccess, video

Developing a site with html5 video, the video works fine in my localhost - MAMP and plays as it should, when it should however I've just put it live in a dev.example.com sub-domain and it is just showing the paused first frame of the video.

I have put the following in the .htaccess file:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

An example of the code used for one of the videos is -

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="manu_apollo2.mp4.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="manu_apollo2.webmhd.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
  <source src="manu_apollo2.theora.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

If you link to videos directly through with the file extension on the domain then they load and work as normal.

Not sure if I'm overlooking something important, I believe I've encoded the videos correctly.

Anything glaringly obvious to anyone...

Many thanks!

Comment: any reason why all of your `<source>` files have two extensions?

Comment: No, no reason. When I encoded them it just automatically made them like that. Should I change this?

Comment: try removing the first extension so they become `manu_apollo2.mp4`, `manu_apollo2.webm`, and `manu_apollo2.ogv`

Comment: that doesn't seem to of changed anything

Comment: It may be to do with the video files being large and the browser waiting to buffer before it starts playing. When running from a localhost the buffer time is negligible.

Comment: I see, I have a carousel of 4 projects with a short video attached to each which also has a extended video which the user will have the option to play. This src that I'm referencing has the following file sizes - MP4/4.9Mb - WebM/4.1Mb - Ogg/8.1Mb is this acceptable for browser speeds etc.

Comment: can you point us to a live link for this?